# Extracting some data from an HTML file and writing it to another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Given that we have an HTML file as shown below:

```
    </pre>
    <pre><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="AAAAAAA.jpg">AAAAAAA.jpg</a>          16-Jan-2008 01:27  827K  
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="AAAAAAA.jpg.xml">AAAAAAA.jpg.xml</a>      16-Jan-2008 01:28   12K
    <img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"> <a href="BBBBB.AAAAAAAA.txt">BBBBB.AAAAAAAA.txt</a> 16-Jan-2008 15:01  1.6K  
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="js421254.jpg">AAAAAAA.jpg</a>          16-Jan-2008 01:27  827K  
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="js421254.jpg.xml">AAAAAAA.jpg.xml</a>      16-Jan-2008 01:28   12K
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"> <a href="BBdBBB.AAAAsaAAAA.txt">BBBBB.AAAAAAAA.txt</a> 16-Jan-2008 15:01  1.6K  
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="52542.jpg">AAAAAAA.jpg</a>          16-Jan-2008 01:27  827K  
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="52542.jpg.xml">AAAAAAA.jpg.xml</a>      16-Jan-2008 01:28   12K
    <hr></pre>
    </body></html>
```

How is it possible to make a new text file containing the characters as shown below:

Expected result:

```
AAAAAAA.jpg
js421254.jpg
...
...
...
52542.jpg
```

Comment: Changed the title to best reflect what you're looking for (operations on an HTML file, not just some plain text file.

Comment: Look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i want to solve it using python with out external dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this regex generalizes correctly:

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile, open('/path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('lt="[   ]"'):
            hrefs = re.findall("\<a\\s+href=.*\</a\>?", line)
            for href in hrefs:
                target = href.split('=', 1)[1].split(">", 1)[0].strip('"')
                outfile.write("%s\n" target)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is **evil** ! :-D => http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @halflings: I know this all too well. Come to think of it, why the heck didn't I look to `xml.dom`?

Comment: There are a lot of malformed HTML out there that will choke straight xml parsers. You need another kind of cop for this job: BeautifulSoup is the [Vic Mackey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vic_Mackey) of the parsers (sorry for the bad joke, I was just watching "the shield" over netflix).

Comment: @PauloScardine: I suggested BS in the comments to the question itself, but OP wants "to solve it using python with out external dependencies"

Comment: The OP isn't really parsing html. He's searching a big string for strings that look like jpg file names... Which is what regex is for.

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is good for webscraping:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon ">
    <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">
    <a href="AAAAAAA.jpg">AAAAAAA.jpg</a>          16-Jan-2008 01:27  827K
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">
    <a href="AAAAAAA.jpg.xml">AAAAAAA.jpg.xml</a>      16-Jan-2008 01:28   12K
    <img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]">
    <a href="BBBBB.AAAAAAAA.txt">BBBBB.AAAAAAAA.txt</a> 16-Jan-2008 15:01  1.6K
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">
    <a href="js421254.jpg">AAAAAAA.jpg</a>          16-Jan-2008 01:27  827K
    <img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]">
    <a href="js421254.jpg.xml">AAAAAAA.jpg.xml</a>      16-Jan-2008 01:28   12K""")

>>> for a in soup.findAll('a'):
...     if str(a.text).strip().lower().endswith('jpg'): print a.text
...
AAAAAAA.jpg
AAAAAAA.jpg
>>>
>>> for a in soup.findAll('a'):
...     if a.get('href').strip().lower().endswith('jpg'): print a.get('href')
... 
AAAAAAA.jpg
js421254.jpg
```

If you want pure Python and your use case is simple enough, you can try regular expressions. This is trickier because in the real world there are a lot of corner cases and malformed HTML out there.

```
import re
>>> for match in re.findall(r'<a .+?>(.+?)</a>', html):
...     if match.strip().lower().endswith('jpg'): print match
...     
AAAAAAA.jpg
AAAAAAA.jpg
>>>
```

Or this if your are looking at the href attribute:

```
>>> for match in re.findall(r'<a href="(.+?)">', html):
...     if match.lower().endswith('jpg'): print match
... 
AAAAAAA.jpg
js421254.jpg
```

If you are just scraping something simple like porn sites you should get good results with regular expressions.

> could you please explain me str(a.text).strip().lower().endswith('jpg')? – guava

- **strip**: this method returns the string without spaces (including tabs and newlines) that occur at the start or end of the string
- **lower**: converts to lower case (so you don't need to test for all the case variations like JPG, jpg, Jpg).
- **endswith**: returns True if the string ends with the argument you provide (the thing you are looking for).

> thank you @Paulo Scardine i also could not understand `re.findall(r'<a href="(.+?)">'`, – guava

Well, the re module is Python implementation of [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) - a vast subject that has books larger than bibles about it (OK, maybe larger than the new testament). I will not pretend I can scratch the surface of it in a stackoverflow answer.

First thing you may find strange is the `r` in front of the quotes. It is a [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html), a string where you don't have to escape the `\` because unlike regular strings, the backslash has no special meaning inside raw strings (backslashes are used all the time in regular expressions, it just occurred to me that I'm not using patterns with backslashes in this case - the power of the habit...)

Now to the expression: the `()` mark the group you want to capture. The dot means any character, the plus sign means one or more of them, and the `?` means the search is not greedy (the default is a greedy search where the `.+` would match any character, including the quotes). Just try the same expression without the `?` and you will understand what happens.

Comment: could you please explain me str(a.text).strip().lower().endswith('jpg')? @Paulo Scardine

Comment: Of course: `strip` will get rid of any spaces at the beginning or end of the name, `lower` will convert to lower case (so you don't have to test for JPG, jpg, Jpg), and `endswith` returns true if the string ends with 'jpg'.

Comment: thank you @Paulo Scardine i also could not understand re.findall(r'<a href="(.+?)">',

Comment: Updated with more info as well.

Comment: thank you very much for your explaination. If you are just scrapping something simple like porn sites..LOL @Paulo Scardine

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for simple parsing, but it all depends on what exactly you want.

You can use something like:

```
<t = html text>
import re
for f in re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.jpg)[^\.]',t):
    print f
```

to find any jpg file in your current list, but if a filename has a `.` then you would have to modify the regex.

If you don't want duplicates you could wrap it in a set like:

```
for f in set(re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.jpg)[^\.]',t)):
```

Explanation of regex:

```
[a-zA-z0-9]+
```

This selects any sequence of one or more characters that's a letter or numeral.

```
\.jpg
```

This selects the exact string `.jpg`

```
[^\.]
```

This means that the next character cannot be `.`

The parenthesis around everything except the last part is everything the regex selects.

Comment: could you please explain me the meaning of '([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.jpg)[^\.]'? @korylprince